# How to install APC or APCu in xampp

Tags: php, xampp, apc

I have been trying to install APC (Alternative PHP Cache). My development environment is windows 7 32-bit, xampp and php 7. I have downloaded dll files of APC and APCu and placed them in `xampp/php/ext` directory. Then I have added the following lines in php.ini file:

```
extension : php_apc.dll
extension : php_apcu.dll
```

After that I restarted the apache. When I look at `phpinfo.php`, I don't see anything there about APC. Could you tell me someone where I did mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Modify the `php.ini` configuration file by placing the below code in the file

extension: `php_apc.dll`

Remove the semicolon (`;`) before the extension if exists.

See more [here](https://arjunphp.com/install-apc-xampp-windows/)

Comment: yes I did as you mentioned and there is no comma before this line.